# Chmod add multiple groups

Tags: unix

I have this command:

```
chmod -R +a 'group:test1 allow  list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit' /PATH
```

Which works fine. Question is, how do I add another group in the same command?

This does not work:

```
chmod -R +a 'group:test1,group:test2 allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit' /PATH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `chmod +a` adds *one* entry to the ACL, and each ACL entry refers to one user or group. From the man page:

> Each file has one ACL, containing an ordered list of entries. Each entry refers to a user or group, and grants or denies a set of permissions.

So you'll need something like

```
for g in test1 test2; do
    chmod -R +a "group:$g allow ... " /path/to/directory
done
```